# How to pass object created in FXML Controller1 to Controller2 of inner FXML control

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I have a JavaFX 2.0 application, which consists of two FXML files, and two controllers for them + one "main" .java file.

At the start time, FXML1 is initialized, like this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Demo Jabber JavaFX Chat");
    
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"),
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("fxmlexample.fxml_example"));        
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 226, 264);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("fxmlexample/fxmlstylesheet.css");
    stage.show();
}
```

Then, when a button from scene1 is clicked, in its event handler in Controller1 class, I change scene1 root, to show new gui-view for a user. And in this controller I initialize some object. For example, like this:

```
public class FXMLExampleController {
   //some fields...
   private MySuperObject c;
   @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    //some fields...
    c = new MySuperObject(); //here i initialize my object, i'm interested in
    try {
        c.login(username, password); // some actions with this object, which i need to make.
        Scene cc = buttonStatusText.getScene();
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            //changing a scene content...
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example2.fxml"),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("fxmlexample.fxml_example"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLExampleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        cc.setRoot(root);
      }
```

And, after that, I have to do some work with that object on the next scene, and it must be NOT a new instance of the same class, but the object which I have initialized on the first one scene.

I understand how to make these all using "standard java", but I'm kind of confused on this task using JavaFX + FXML.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In FX 2.2 new API for controller-node was introduced:

```
// create class which is both controller and node
public class InnerFxmlControl extends HBox implements Initializable {
  @FXML public ComboBox cb;

  public InnerFxmlControl () {
     FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml_example2.fxml"));
     fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
     fxmlLoader.setController(this);
     try {
         fxmlLoader.load();            
     } catch (IOException exception) {
         throw new RuntimeException(exception);
     }
  }
```

with next fxml (note tag `fx:root`):

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <ComboBox fx:id="cb" />
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

By this you've created a new control, which you can use as regular JavaFX controls. E.g. in your case:

```
@FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    // you just create new control, all fxml tricks are encapsulated
    InnerFxmlControl root = new InnerFxmlControl();
    // and you can access all its' methods and fields including matched by @FXML tag:
    root.cb.getItems().add("new item");

    Scene cc = buttonStatusText.getScene();
    cc.setRoot(root);
  }
```

and in fxml:

```
<InnerFxmlControl />
```

Comment: What are the root.cb. **minutes** .getItems().add("new item"); and  **cc** .setRoot(root); in last code piece?

Comment: Sorry, `minutes` are from wrong copy-paste. And `cc` from original Victoria's code sample. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

i'm using 1.7.0_21,
it can now code like this:
in main app fxml file ,

```
<VBox ...>
      <fx:include fx:id="tom" source="Tom.fxml" />
</VBox>
```

and the included fxml can defind it's own fxml file , like this :

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="tomPan" ... xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="**com.tom.fx.TomController**">
```

and then , in the main application contoller require the "Tom.fxml" 's controller like this :

```
 @FXML private TomController tomController;
```

notice the "@FXML" . maybe it invoke the contoller automatic.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! One question: the fx:id is tom but the injected controller is named tomController? By what mechanism are they associated?

Comment: JavaFX inject "Controller" to fx:id.

Comment: In case it was unclear, javaFX will automatically inject the controller into field named <id>Controller. So if the fx:id="tom" it will inject an instance of the controller into a field called tomController.