# JavaFX class controller scene reference

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

Is there any way of getting the Scene object of an FXML loaded file from the associated class controller.

I'm doing something like this:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchor; 

Scene scene = anchor.getScene();
```

but i'd like a solution that does not reference the AnchorPane control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not? Controller is an abstract class, he's not aware about UI unless you deliberately make him know.

Nodes (inlcuding AnchorPane) are another story, they hardly exists outside for scenegraph. So it's perfectly fine to ask Node about his parent or scene.

If you still want to handle that separately there are next approaches:

1. you can create a custom controller and set scene after loader. Just note that at the time `initialize()` called it wouldn't yet initialized.

   ```
   public class MyController {
       private void Scene scene;
       public void setScene(Scene scene) { this.scene = scene; }

   }

   // loading code
   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
   AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyApp.fxml"));
   MyController myController = (MyController) fxmlLoader.getController();
   myController.setScene(scene);
   ```
2. You can create a custom fxml control which will incorporate controller and he can just call `getScene()` for itself. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718683/1054140

Comment: @netskink, fixed it for you

Comment: FXMLLoader.load() is static method therefore fxmlLoader.getController() will return null. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your answer, but it did not work, I found the reason here:
[JavaFX: How to get stage from controller during initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246211/javafx-how-to-get-stage-from-controller-during-initialization)
after the comment:

```
// loading code
```

don't use the static load method

```
AnchorPane root=(AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyApp.fxml"));
```

but instead use instantiated loader's method

```
AnchorPane root=(AnchorPane) fxmlLoaded.load(getClass().getResource("MyApp.fxml"));
```

Comment: How is this different to the answer already posted? That answer was using the instance method, not a static load method.

Comment: @AaronD, I edited the accepted answer to correct it, for the sake of future users who will read it. Most likely it was a typo while posting the answer.

Comment: oh thanks, although u missed one entry of fxmlLoader, I fixed that.