# How to center a popup?

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

So I am using jfoenix JFXPopup component for my popup. After finally getting the popup to show. I realized that the popup is displayed relative to a owner node you pass it. My question is there any way to display the pop up relative to the scene so I can center it?

Unfortunately you can not center the popup over the owner node, you can only move it up down or left and right?

[Popup relative to the search textfield in the middle of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqp4q.png)

```
//Current Code
@FXML
    protected void handleLoginButton(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Popup BUtton clicked");
        if (!loginPopup.isShowing()) {
            System.out.println("Popup is open!");
            //loginPopup.show(searchBtn, JFXPopup.PopupVPosition.BOTTOM, JFXPopup.PopupHPosition.LEFT);
            loginPopup.show(searchBtn);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use root pane of scene when you call `show`, and calculate center position;

```
popupRoot.setPrefWidth(200);
popupRoot.setPrefHeight(300);
button.setOnAction(event -> {
    JFXPopup loginPopup = new JFXPopup(popupRoot);
    Bounds rootBounds = scene.getRoot().getLayoutBounds();
    loginPopup.show(scene.getRoot(), JFXPopup.PopupVPosition.TOP, JFXPopup.PopupHPosition.LEFT,
            (rootBounds.getWidth() - popupRoot.getPrefWidth()) / 2,
            (rootBounds.getHeight() - popupRoot.getPrefHeight()) / 2);
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935953/javafx-class-controller-scene-reference) to access the scene from your controller.