# Is using fx:root a requirement to setting a controller programmatically?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

Everywhere I see explanations on the use o FXMLLoader#setController() it's associated with using fx:root and also setting a root node programmatically (both [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxmlloader) and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717852/how-to-pass-object-created-in-fxml-controller1-to-controller2-of-inner-fxml-cont) have this pattern).
Is it a requirement? Or can I create a regular FXML (probably using SceneBuilder) with some good old container and set **only** the controller programmatically later?

In FXML:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" > </Borderpane>
```

In some code (probably a controller):

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml_example2.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
try {
    fxmlLoader.load();            
} catch (IOException exception) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is a requirement.  I've got this working by tweaking the [Oracle tutorial code](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) to look like this in my Application class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(new ExampleController());
    Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    stage.show();
}
```

As you can see I've set my ExampleController programatically rather than using the `fx:controller="ExampleController"` in the FXML and I didn't have to set `id:root` anywhere to do it.

As an aside, I quite like this approach as it mimics more closely setting the data context in MVVM with WPF and further decouples the view from the controller.

Comment: I've also seen it show up in some FXML based components lately.