# clear mvc separation in javxfx fxml

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx-2, fxml

I have a simple Javafx desktop application and I'm trying to split the code to match the mvc pattern, but my problem is that I have a nested class containing a MediaPlayer in the Application (which is part of the view in my opinion).

I want to call methods of this MediaPlayer in my Controller, to get the State for example, but it's not visible there. Can I have a clean MVC separation in a JavaFX FXML application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a nested class an FXML component (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718683/1054140) and introduce a property which will return state (or even MediaView itself) to make it accessible from Controller.