# Update FXML Screen

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to update a Screen, which i created with a FXML-file.

I though this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class) was the solution, but i dont get the code to run. I found some other parts of code but no one worked for me. I am not shure if i use a different version (see [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717852/how-to-pass-object-created-in-fxml-controller1-to-controller2-of-inner-fxml-cont/10718683#10718683)) or maybe i am just an idot... but we will see...

I made a very simple exampel to show my problem, so that hopefully someone can show me on this simple example how it works.

JavaFXApplication.java

```
package javafxapplication;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
package javafxapplication;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        label.setText("This Label was initialized.");
    }    

    public void update(){
        label.setText("This Label was updated :)"); //Just4Example... normaly here is some SQL-Stuff...
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="100" layoutY="100" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I want to start the "update"-Methode in the controller every 5 seconds. But when i use a Timer to do this... the Controller is gone. So when the Timer starts the Methode there are no @FXML connections... Maybe the Controller should created manualy... or linke the second linke... but i dont get the code to run... confused... frustrated...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    label.setText("This Label was initialized.");
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            // Call update method for every 2 sec.
            update();
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

However using timeline in SQL query task will block UI JavaFX thread, causing the screen to freeze while querying. So use [ScheduledService](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) (introduced in JavaFX 8) instead.

Comment: I got an Error at "new EventHandler<ActionEvent() {" - The Error: "cannot find symbol symbol:constructor ()   type EventHandler does not take parameters"

Comment: @user2111880, did you import javafx.event.EventHandler and javafx.event.ActionEvent? Check it.

Comment: I had a diffrent EventHandler import... but i still got errors... these are my import: import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration; are they correct?

Comment: sorry... sometimes writing a problem solves it ;) i chancent also import javafx.event.ActionEvent;... now it works - thank you very much