# Getting data from one controller to another

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get access fields of one controller from another controller, but I'm not having much luck. Basically,  I have a Tabpane with two tabs, each of which has its own controller.  I have a button on the first tab and a text field on the other. On clicking the button, it should add text to the text field.

I've read some of the ways to fix the problem on here, but none of them worked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[Accessing FXML controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class)

[How to pass object created in FXML Controller1 to Controller2 of inner FXML control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717852/how-to-pass-object-created-in-fxml-controller1-to-controller2-of-inner-fxml-cont/10718683#10718683)

And some google pages

**Tab controllers**

Utab1ViewController

```
package com.example.myproject;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Utab1ViewController implements Initializable {

    private Utab2ViewController utab2ViewCtrl;
    private Utab2ViewController getUtab2ViewCtrl() throws Exception {
        if(utab2ViewCtrl == null) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("utab2-view.fxml").openStream());
            utab2ViewCtrl = (Utab2ViewController) loader.getController();
        }

        return utab2ViewCtrl;
    }

    @FXML
    private void onClickEvent() {
        try {
            getUtab2ViewCtrl().updatePage("test1");
            System.out.println("test");
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    }
}
```

Utab2ViewController

```
package com.example.myproject;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Utab2ViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TextField txtMessage;

    public void updatePage(String str) {
        txtMessage.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

**FXML files**

utab1-view.fxml

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.nhsbsajavafx.Utab1ViewController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="cmdHello" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hello!" onMouseClicked="#onClickEvent"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

utab2-view.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.nhsbsajavafx.Utab2ViewController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtMessage" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="125.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Your `getUtab2ViewController()` method loads an FXML file, which creates a copy of the UI defined in that file, and then gets the controller for that UI. But then you never display that UI, so when you call `updatePage(…)` it will update a text field that isn’t displayed. I’m guessing (and without a [mre] I have to guess) that elsewhere in your code you are loading and displaying that FXML. You need to get the controller that’s created when you load the FXML *and display it*. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187963/2189127

Comment: A better solution might be to use an MVC approach. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342864/2189127